# Android spinner custom layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

I am trying to customize my spinner with custom style.

**Spinner**

```
<Spinner
            android:id="@+id/my_spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/expense_amount"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="parent"
            android:elevation="3dp"
            />
```

Here is my styles.xml file.

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:spinnerStyle">@style/AppTheme.spinnerStyle</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/AppTheme.spinnerDropDownItemStyle</item>

</style>
<style name="AppTheme.spinnerStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.Spinner">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>

</style>
<style name="AppTheme.spinnerDropDownItemStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.DropDownItem.Spinner">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

This gives me spinners that look like this:
[image: Spinner Image]

I want to add a dropdown arrow.
When I change the spinner to code for dropdown arrow, all the textcolor and background color are lost.

**Spinner code to show dropdown arrow**

```
<Spinner
            android:id="@+id/my_spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/expense_amount"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="parent"
            android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
            />
```

[image: Spinner with dropdown arrow]

How can I retain my theme along with the drop down arrow ??

**P.S.** I am not very good at capturing screenshots on linux machines.

Comment: Just a shortcut - add an `ImageView` with src as arrow and set `spinner.showDropDown();` in onClickListener of that `ImageView`.

Answer (score 0):

It's normal behaviour of Android:

Spinner have it's own default background, when you use `styles.xml` to custom it, it follow and turn to blue. Then in the code you again set the `android:background` of your Spinner to `@android:drawable/btn_dropdown`, so it override your styles because properties in layout xml have higher priority than in styles.

You don't have background to show dropdown arrow, use this:

**First solution:**

```
<Spinner
      android:id="@+id/spinner"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
      android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
```

and in your java file

```
spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.spinner_data, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**Second solution**

You will need a RelativeLayout wrap outside Spinner. Replace your `<Spinner>` with this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/spinner_bg">
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then create a custom background and choose background color for your spinner:

**spinner_bg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:top="8dp" android:bottom="8dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
            <corners android:radius="2dp"/>
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
            <padding
                android:top="16dp"
                android:bottom="16dp"
                android:left="8dp"
                android:right="16dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: I got the arrow on right side but  it doesn't show any item. Items are shown in the dropdown when clicking the arrow.

Comment: @Tony what did you get now? please send my a picture.

Comment: Sorry. I was lost in some other work.  I just get an arrow instead of a button. When I click on it, it shows the drop-down list perfectly with all my theme. But I really don't know how to create a spinner with arrow and having my own custom  theme in a standard way.  
I am done with customising  spinnerss !!!!

Comment: @Tony Workaround, quickest way: Find a drawable which have a dropdown icon and have  blue background. In `styles.xml` replace your drawable in this `<item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>`

Comment: Ok @nhoxbypass I will try it out. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Tony I've updated the answer. Please try the 2nd way.